# In Python, is referencing an instance variable from a staticmethod possible?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance, static-methods

I know the question has been asked before, but I find myself bumping into situations where a staticmethod is most appropriate, but there is also a need to reference an instance variable inside this class. As an example, lets say I have the following class:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, filename = 'defaultFilename'):
        self.file_name = filename

    @staticmethod
    def doSomethingWithFiles(file_2, file_1 = None):
         #if user didn't supply a file use the instance variable 
         if file_1 is None:
            # no idea how to handle the uninitialized class case to create
            # self.file_name. 
            file_1 = __class__.__init__().__dict__['file_name'] <--- this seems sketchy
         else:
            file_1 = file_1
         with open(file_1, 'r') as f1, open(file_2, 'w') as f2:
            .....you get the idea...

    def moreMethodsThatUseSelf(self):
        pass
```

Now suppose I had  a few instances of the ExampleClass (E1, E2, E3) with different filenames passed into __init__, but want to retain the ability to use either an uninitialized class ExampleClass.doSomethingWithFiles(file_2 = E1.file_name, file_1 = E2.file_name) or E1.doSomethingWithFiles(file_2 = E2.file_name, file_1 = 'some_other_file') as the situation requires.

Is there any reason for me to trying to find a way to do what I am thinking, or am I making a mess?

**UPDATE**
I think the comments are helpful and I also think it's an issue I'm encountering due to bad design.

The issue started out as a way to prevent concurrent access to HDF5 files by giving each class instance an rlock that I could use as a context manager for preventing any other attempts to access the file while it was in use. Each class instance had it's own rlock it acquired and released when done with whatever it needed to do. I was also using @staticmethod to perform a routine that then generated a file which was passed into it's own **init**() and was unique to each class instance. At the time it seemed clever, but I regret it. I also think I am entirely unsure of when @staticmethods are ever appropriate and maybe was confusing it with @classmethods, but a class variable would no longer make the rlocks and files that are unique to my class instances possible. I think I should probably just think more about design vs. trying to justify using a class definition I do not really understand in a manner it was designed to protect against.

Comment: You are making a mess. The one and only reason for a static method to exist is to not give you access to the instance. It sounds like you just want a normal method.

Comment: If you get an answer you should accept it - If it is left *open*, it cannot be used as a proposed duplicate if someone else asks  question similar enough to yours.

Comment: I actually haven't been able to figure out the reason static method were considered necessary since I am not sure why someone would need to write a class method, but not want any affiliation to the class it was defined in.. I probably just need a vacation.

Comment: They are not considered necessary. Indeed, they were a relatively late addition to Python. As far as I can tell, it was included to appease Java devs.

Comment: @wwii - so far, the answers have been "don't do it". It's not as helpful as a redundant attempt to extract a deeper solution. I tried to at least show a case where it crept up on me, and offered my own ideas for working around it. If it happens to others, it happens enough to have a better resource available to others than "start over". Bad design is everyone else's code, but mine's great. When it works. And will never require modifying or expanding. You understand the point I'm making I am sure.

Comment: Here's a good example of a good use for a staticmethod (as seen multiple times in the stdlib): You have an instance attribute whose value is a function, e.g., `self.callback`. Now you want to provide a default value for it. Class attributes can be used as default values for instance attributes—but `callback = lambda msg: None` at class level defines a method, not a function. `callback = staticmethod(lambda msg: None)` avoids that and gives you a plain function, as intended. (Notice that the whole point is to _not_ be a method, and therefore _not_ have a `self`.)

Comment: @BrandonJ Bad design isn’t everyone else’s code, it’s my code from 6 months ago or more. The way I want to rewrite it of course the very definition of good design—but only for the first 6 months. :) Anyway, if you want more info on what actually are good uses for class and static methods, I have an incomplete blog post from a few years ago I could finish up and link to. But it may be easier to just grep through the stdlib and see how the core developers use them.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for sharing this: It makes sense, but juuust barely. You've inspired me to read more documentation. If you want to finish your blog post and send me a link, I will definitely read it. If you have a programming blog already and do not feel like finishing the incomplete post, but don't mind sharing your link, I'll read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think you keep bumping into situations where a staticmethod is most appropriate, you're probably wrong—good uses for them are very rare. And if your staticmethod needs to access instance variables, you're *definitely* wrong.

A staticmethod cannot access instance variables directly. There can be no instances of the class, or a thousands; which one would you access the variables from?

---

What you're trying to do is to create a new instance, just to access its instance variables. This can occasionally be useful—although it's more often a good sign you didn't need a class in the first place. (And, when it useful, it's unusual enough to be usually worth signaling, by having the caller write `ExampleClass().doSomethingWithFiles` instead of `ExampleClass.doSomethingWithFiles`.)

That's legal, but you do it by just calling the class, not by calling its `__init__` method. That `__init__` never returns anything; it receives an already-created `self` and modifies it. If you really want to, you can call its `__new__` method, but that effectively just means the same thing as calling the class. (In the minor ways in which they're different, it's calling the class that you want.)

Also, once you've got an instance, you can just use it normally; you don't need to look at its `__dict__`. (Even if you only had the attribute name as a string variable, `getattr(obj, name)` is almost always what you want there, not `obj.__dict__[name]`.)

So:

```
file_1 = __class__().file_name
```

---

So, what should you do instead?

Well, look at your design. The only thing an `ExampleClass` instance does is hold a filename, which has a default value. You don't need an object for that, just a plain old string variable that you pass in, or store as a global. (You may have heard that global variables are bad—but global variables in disguise are just as bad, and have the additional problem that they're in disguise. And that's basically what you've designed. And sometimes, global variables are the right answer.)

Comment: It's my design and kind of grew uglier over time. I added an update that hopefully illustrates how I got here. Initially filename was an hdf5store handle and one of the instance variables was an rlock. At the time I thought I was being prudent since I ruined a couple files with concurrent read/writes, but I didn't think about how difficult it would be to work with these outside of the class instance they were associated with. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what your intentions are but I think you're misusing the default parameter.
It appears you're trying to use `'defaultFilename'` as the default parameter value. Why not just skip the awkward

```
 if file_1 is None:
        # no idea how to handle the uninitialized class case to create
        # self.file_name. 
        file_1 = __class__.__init__().__dict__['file_name'] <--- this seems sketchy
```

and change the function as follows,

```
def doSomethingWithFiles(file_2, file_1='defaultFilename'):
```

If hardcoding that value makes you uncomfortable maybe try

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    DEFAULT_FILE_NAME = 'defaultFilename'

    def __init__(self, filename=DEFAULT_FILE_NAME):
        self.file_name = filename

    @staticmethod
    def doSomethingWithFiles(file_2, file_1=DEFAULT_FILE_NAME):
         with open(file_1, 'r') as f1, open(file_2, 'w') as f2:
            # do magic in here

    def moreMethodsThatUseSelf(self):
        pass
```

In general, though, you're probably modeling your problem wrong if you want to access an instance variable inside a static method.

Comment: I provided an update that makes a better case for how/why I got into this. hdf5 store handles and rlocks unique to the class that was responsible for working with the file seemed like a good idea, but quickly got out of control. I also have no idea when to use @staticmethod and should pretend it doesn't exist, but that really bothers me because I know it is there and probably does something extremely useful when there's a real need for it. I just haven't found the model case for which it was designed

Answer (score 0):

why not input the instance as parameter to static method. I hope this code will be helpful.

```
 class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def print(self):
        print('fname=', self.fname)

    @staticmethod
    def check(f):
        if type(f)==ClassA :
            print('f is exist.')
            f.print()
            print('f.fname=', f.fname)
        else:
            print('f is not exist: new ClassA')
            newa = ClassA(f)
            return newa


a=ClassA('temp')
b=ClassA('test')
ClassA.check(a)
ClassA.check(b)
newa = ClassA.check('hello')
newa.print()
```

Comment: I need to sit down and look at this more since I have hit my mental limit on code for the day, but I really appreciate your solution. It actually looks like it might solve some of my problem without requiring me to redo everything. I'll definitely let you know when I look at this more when I'm more refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to an instance attribute from a static method. Suppose multiple instances exist, which one would you pick the attribute from?

What you seem to need is to have a class attribute and a class method. You can define one by using the `classmethod` decorator.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    file_name = 'foo'

    @classmethod
    def doSomethingWithFiles(cls, file_2, file_1 = None):
        file_1 = cls.file_name
        # Do stuff
```

Comment: What if the class variable was an rlock and class instances were working with data files that were specific to a class instance and the static method generated this file from other files and passed it to itself as it's unique data file while the rlock was supposed to prevent other class instances from ruining a particular class instance's data file and class instances occasionally used other class instance's data files for some calculations? I think I'm destroying my own brain and designing something I shouldn't be.

Comment: Starting from scratch may be a good option here. I am not sure to understand exactly what you need, but it does seem you need to rethink a better architecture.

Comment: @ Olivier Melançon -  I think you are probably right, or at least stopping is a good idea. I did an especially terrible job explaining the case, which I should have tried coding up and presenting instead of the sample example in my original question.